# Java text highliting

Tags: java

I did a code in java for file comparison. This compares two file contents and gives a result like :  modified line and deleted lines and blank lines. I want them to highlight with different color. (Same as a file compare software does).

Thanks in advance.

Nitin

Comment: This depends a lot on the output device.  Are you writing a web app that does this?  Is it a stand-alone windows app?

Comment: Text comparison is the core part and i need to highlight the text while i show the file in the UI.

Comment: What UI? Spend more time asking your question and less thanking random people.

Comment: Sure. UI, i mean to say the page we user view.

Comment: I am using a browser right now.  However, you may intend to run the application as a stand-alone java app.  The output to display the colors is very different in these two cases.

Comment: You need to be more specific. How is your application being used and what UI are you providing to your users?

Comment: some code perhaps, where exactly are you stuck? or you haven't started yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JTextPane` it supports attributed text which means you can change font, colour, etc.